# regular expression just beginning of email

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email

I want to validate just the beginning of an email address. I will force the user to use my '@company.com' domain, so it is not important to use that. This is the regular expression I'm using:

```
var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]$/
```

And I'm testing it with an alert.

```
alert(validateEmail.test([$(this).attr('value')]));
```

The value pulled via jQuery is the user input. Everything I test alerts as `false`. Does anyone see why? From what I understand, this should mean: beginning of line, character set for alpha-numeric plus the `. _ % + -` symbols, then end of line. What am I doing wrong? Even just an 'a' alerts as `false`.

Comment: Looks like you're only matching one character. It should probably be `[...]+`

Comment: `$(this).val()` is likely easier to read than `$(this).attr('value')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only matches single character. You need to add + sign or {min, max} to specify minimum and maximum length.

```
var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will only match a single character from your set, add a `+` to match at least one character from your set:

```
var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+$/;
```

And you've neglected to include lower-case characters to your regex object:

```
var validateEmail = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+$/;
```

Or set the *ignore-case* flag:

```
var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues.

- `a` fails because it is lower case and your regular expression is case sensitive. You can use the `i` option to ignore casing.
- most other valid email adresses would fail because your regular expression only allows 1 character. you can use the `+` after the character class `[...]` to allow one or more characters, or `*` to allow 0 or more.

`var validateEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+$/i;`